# CSS, input no firefox mostra texto em branco

Tags: html, css, css3

No firefox o texto de minha input nao aparece, qual motivo? veja

http://jsfiddle.net/m8j873y8/

```
input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #595959;
    padding-top: 17px;
    padding-right: 17px;
    padding-bottom: 17px;
    padding-left: 35px !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #FFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
    outline: 0px none;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: border 0.5s ease 0s;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O teu problema, como referido pelo [bfavaretto♦](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/44212/223) é o fato de estares a indicar ao navegador que o tamanho da caixa de texto deve conter o `padding` e a `border`:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Isto está a fazer com que o `input` fique com tamanho 0 (zero):

[image: Box Model]

Como está sem tamanho, o que é escrito não aparece no mesmo, apesar de estar lá:

[image: Captura de tela]

<sup>Animação do teu `input` a transitar de `35px` altura para `55px` de altura fazendo uso do inspetor do navegador.</sup>

## Solução

Dado estares a fazer uso da propriedade `box-sizing` com o valor `border-box`, podes remover o `padding-top` e o `padding-bottom` do `input` que vais obter o mesmo resultado com a vantagem do texto ficar visível.

Como a altura do teu `input` é superior ao indicado na propriedade `height` do mesmo, alterei também no exemplo a altura de `35px` para `38px`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
input.old {
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #595959;
    padding-top: 17px;
    padding-right: 17px;
    padding-bottom: 17px;
    padding-left: 35px !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #FFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
    outline: 0px none;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: border 0.5s ease 0s;
    opacity: 1;
}
input.new {
    width: 100%;
    height: 38px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #595959;
    padding-right: 17px;
    padding-left: 35px !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #FFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
    outline: 0px none;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: border 0.5s ease 0s;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="old" value="Bubu está escondido">
<br>    
<input type="text" class="new" value="Bubu está aqui!">
```

---

Exemplo também no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/hvcr1dc9/).

Comment: Nossa, que complexo, nao sabia dessas regras, grande explicação, Obrigado!

Comment: Muito bem detalhado Zuul, a imagem animada com certeza explica muito bem o problema +1

Answer (score 2):

O Firefox está respeitando o `box-sizing` que você indicou. Quando você usa `border-box`, a altura do elemento inclui bordas e *padding*. Tecnicamente você até ultrapassou a altura definida, e o Firefox está cortando a parte de dentro do elemento para respeitar a altura que você pediu:

```
 17px de padding-top
 17px de padding-bottom
  2px de border-top
  2px de border-botom
-----------------------
 38px no total (mais que os 35 que você definiu!)
```

Não sei qual é a aparência final desejada, mas as soluções passam por alterar o `box-sizing` (ou remover essa propriedade e usar o default), alterar o `height` ou reduzir os paddings.

Comment: A explicação sobre o `box-sizing` está muito correta, +1

Answer (score 1):

O problema está no uso `padding`, ao usa-lo é como se você o ele move-se o texto excessivamente para fora da área de visão do próprio elemento

Se você remover o `padding-top` e o `padding-bottom` o texto irá aparecer, segue um exemplo comentando os "paddings":

```
input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #595959;
    /*padding-top: 17px;
    padding-right: 17px;
    padding-bottom: 17px;*/
    padding-left: 35px !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #FFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
    outline: 0px none;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: border 0.5s ease 0s;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

> Nota: Não é um bom usar `padding-top` e `padding-bottom` com um `height` fixo.

Answer (score 1):

Acabei de testar e deu certo! Tenta isso. . .

```css
input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #595959;   
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #FFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
    outline: 0px none;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: border 0.5s ease 0s;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value ="Hello World" >
```